# Reducing amount of RAM BFS algorithm takes

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, heap-dump

I have written a 2x2x2 rubiks cube solver that uses a breadth first search algorithm to solve a cube position entered by the user. The program does solve the cube. However I encounter a problem when I enter in a hard position to solve which would be found deep in the search, I run out of heap space. My computer only has 4 GB of RAM and when I run the program I give 3GB to it. I was wondering what I could do to reduce the amount of ram the search takes. Possibly by changing a few aspects of the BFS.

```
static private void solve(Cube c) {

    Set<Cube> cubesFound = new HashSet<Cube>();
    cubesFound.add(c);

    Stack<Cube> s = new Stack<Cube>();
    s.push(c);

    Set<Stack<Cube>> initialPaths = new HashSet<Stack<Cube>>();
    initialPaths.add(s);

    solve(initialPaths, cubesFound);
}

static private void solve(Set<Stack<Cube>> livePaths, Set<Cube> cubesFoundSoFar) {
    System.out.println("livePaths size:" + livePaths.size());
    int numDupes = 0;

    Set<Stack<Cube>> newLivePaths = new HashSet<Stack<Cube>>();

    for(Stack<Cube> currentPath : livePaths) {

        Set<Cube> nextStates = currentPath.peek().getNextStates();

        for (Cube next : nextStates) {
            if (currentPath.size() > 1 && next.isSolved()) {
                currentPath.push(next);
                System.out.println("Path length:" + currentPath.size());
                System.out.println("Path:" + currentPath);
                System.exit(0);

            } else if (!cubesFoundSoFar.contains(next)) {
                Stack<Cube> newCurrentPath = new Stack<Cube>();
                newCurrentPath.addAll(currentPath);
                newCurrentPath.push(next);
                newLivePaths.add(newCurrentPath);
                cubesFoundSoFar.add(next);
            } else {
                numDupes += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    String storeStates = "positions.txt";
    try {
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(storeStates);
        outputStream.println(cubesFoundSoFar);
        outputStream.println(storeStates);
        outputStream.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("Duplicates found " + numDupes + ".");
    solve(newLivePaths, cubesFoundSoFar);
}
```

That is the BFS but I fear that its not all the information needed to understand what is going on so here is the link to file with all the code. https://github.com/HaginCodes/2x2-Cube-Solver/blob/master/src/com/haginonyango/pocketsolver/Cube.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition, "Best first search" keeps the entire search frontier of possible paths through the space.

That can be exponentially large.   With 3x3x3 Rubik's cube, I think there are 12? possible moves at each point, so a 10 move sequence to solve arguably requires 12^10 combinations which is well over a billion (10^9).  WIth this many states, you'll want to minimize the size of the state to minimize total storage.  (Uh, you actually *print* all the states? "  outputStream.println(cubesFoundSoFar);" Isnt that a vast amount of output?)

With 2x2x2, you only have 8 possible moves at each point.  I don't know solution lengths here for random problems.  If it is still length 10, you get 8^10 which is still pretty big.

Now,  many move sequences lead to the same cube configuration.  To recognize this you need to check that a generated move does not re-generate a position already visited.  You seem to be doing that (good!) and tracking the number of hits; I'd expect that hit count to be pretty high as many paths should lead to the same configuration.

What you don't show, is how you score each move sequence to guide the search.  What node does it expand next?  This is where *best* comes into play.   If you don't have any guidance (e.g., all move sequences enumerated have the same value), you truly will wander over a huge space because all move sequences are equally good.   What guides your solver to a solution?  You need something like a priority queue over nodes with priority being determined by score, and that I don't see in the code you presented here.

I don't know what a great heuristic for measuring the score as a quality of a move sequence, but you can start by scoring a move sequence with the number of moves it takes to arrive there.  The next "best move" to try is then the one with the shortest path.   That will probably help immensely.

(A simple enhancement that might work is to count the number of colors on a face; 3 colors hints [is this true?] that it might take 3-1 --> 2 moves minimum to remove the wrong colors.  Then the score might be #moves+#facecolors-1, to estimate number of moves to a solution; clearly you want the shortest sequence of moves. This might be a so-called "admissible" hueristic score).

You'll also have to adjust your scheme to detecting duplicate move sequences.  When you find an already encountered state, that state will now presumably have attached to it the score (move count) it takes to reach that state.  When you get a hit, you've found another way to get to that same state... but the score for new path, may be *smaller* than what is recorded in the state.  In this case, you need to revise the score of discovered duplicate state with the smaller new score.   This way a path/state with score 20 may in fact be discovered to have a score of 10, which means it is suddenly improved.

Comment: The terminology for the 2x2x2 cube is slightly different. There are 8 pieces and they can be laid out in 8! potential orders, and each piece has 3 possible orientations (because each piece is a corner with 3 colors). That would give us 8! * 3^7 possible combinations. Most notably, the entire cube has 6 possible sides that could be facing towards us, and for each of those 6 sides facing us we could rotate the cube clockwise or counter clockwise to make 4 different colors show up on the top. That means there are 8! * 3^7 / (6*4) potential combinations (3.6 million). @Ira Baxter

Comment: Also I do write these positions out because I intend on having a file that contains all the positions and when the user wants to solve their cube it will search the file containing all of them and with each position in the file is the turns it took to get from that position to a solved state. So I would just fetch that position and its solution with it and print it out on the screen which is much shorter than searching all again.

Comment: I also avoid duplicate positions because the cube never rotates I perform moves on a cube for testing that can reach any position of the puzzle without having to rotate the puzzle so running into duplicate positions is not an issue each position is unique. To answer your question about what guides my solver to solve the cube is that I have a Set of turns I try on the puzzle that could potentially solve it and it goes though those move patterns over and over again to different states of the cube looking for a solution.

Comment: Then you don't have a "best first search" in spite of your title.

Comment: My guess for 2x2x2 cube with a good *best* first solver, that it isn't worth writing the answers to a file.  You can probably solve it faster than opening a file, so just solve it.  I suspect things aren't so good for 3x3x3 or larger.

Comment: Regarding duplicate detections: yes, you can take a generated cube, and orient it in canonical way.   This will increase the number of duplicates you encounter, and decrease your search time/space costs.

Comment: It is a best first search though because if finds the fewest amount of moves it takes to solve the cube. It is a best first search because it is a single phase solver. For other puzzles like 3x3x3 and beyond they are multiphase because it is practically impossible to generate 43 quintillion positions for a 3x3x3 cube and search them. So solving the cube in steps and having files that have all the positions for those steps makes it possible.

Comment: RIchard Korf (UCLA researcher) treats Rubik's cube like a lab rat and has all kinds of research papers on how to solve it.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_solutions_for_Rubik's_Cube  Basically he uses lots of clever search variations to avoid generating states, but he also generates LOTS of states. His solution I think dates back into the early 90s, with machines 100-1000x slower than what you have.

Comment: If it is best first search, where in your code (I don't see in what you have in your question) where does it select the next "best move" to expand?

Comment: The reason why it is best first search is because it doesn't hit duplicate positions. As you noted earlier there are positions that can be hit using different moves to get there. This is not possible if you don't rotate the cube and make sure the turns you perform on the 2x2x2 cube orbit around one piece. I have that in place so I cannot hit a duplicate position which means that I can't go searching down a path I have already been down before because it can't be reached. The solver is forced to try a new state.

Comment: For every state it is testing lets take one for example it will try the first move in the hashset with the turns then the next one and the following etc. And because it is the first one of its kind it is testing it is the shortest route from that position to the solved state.

Comment: Not if it is a duplicate; the just discovered path to the duplicate may be shorter, but you throw that away when you hit it.  What you should do is promote it the order (eg., "priority").   So you aren't always searching for the shortest path.

Comment: The just discovered path to the duplicate cannot be shorter because by having each position being tested by the same moves it would all be redundant and everything down that path would be longer. I used to have these duplicates and there were a lot but I figured out how to get rid of them.

Comment: Tested by the same moves?  You mean, you expand all moves at the same depth on each iteration?  Check out Korf's IDA* as a search algorithm; uses space linear in depth at the price of some repeated work.

Comment: I have a Set in the code project called `getNextStates` in this set it takes the methods that turn the cube to get it into a new position. It does them in order of call. I have one there that calls a specific turn it will try each turn to see if it can make the boolean `isSolved` `true`. If it can't it will try a different state of the cube and see if it can solve it.

Comment: robots like this one here are using the same type of reasoning I am using for my solver as well. All the positions and their solutions have been generated and are then stored in a file. You can then search the file for the position of the puzzle you have and then print out the moves it takes to solve the cube. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_d0LfkIut2M